# Computer shuts down at any attempt to install an OS

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, operating-systems

So, asking for a friend, she recently bought a custom computer with no preinstalled OS.
She has tried to install both windows 10 and Ubuntu, but as soon as she gets to the installation part of the process the computer shuts down.
Any idea where the problem could be coming from? And how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Is the computer "just bought"? If so, bring it back to the seller. FWIW `memtest86` is free to download and use - run it to possibly detect memory problems.

Comment: @Hannu yeah, pretty much. It was bought in separate pieces and another friend built it for her. If we can isolate the hardware cause we can probably take it back

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated to provide an accurate tip in this case, but it seems like a hardware problem to me. Usually when there's a hardware problem, the computer freezes or shutsdown at random situations, so if you have tried installing two different OS's and same happens I'd blame the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like processor overheating.

1. Check processor cooler is working properly.
2. Check thermopaste between processor and cooler.

Answer (score 0):

please check the following

- RAM: remove every stick but one, then test is (but that usually yields in an error in windows instead of shutting down)
- Cooling: Check temperatures in BIOS after having it running about 10 min in BIOS screen